# ERROR: bad DVC file name 'Training_Batch_Files\Wafer12_20012.csv.dvc' is git-ignored

Tags: python, git, dvc

Getting the error "*ERROR: bad DVC file name 'Training_Batch_Files\Wafer12_20012.csv.dvc' is git-ignored.*" while trying to add local files for tracking

Python Version : 3.7

Library used:

`pip install dvc  pip install dvc[gdrive]   dvc init`

**dvc add -R Training_Batch_Files**

[image]

Comment: Did you previously `dvc add Training_Batch_Files\Wafer12_20012.csv`? Please also share `dvc version` and if possible the verbose output of the command that fails (add `-v`).

Comment: Also, is `Training_Batch_Files\Wafer12_20012.csv.dvc` listed in a .gitignore file? If so do you know why? (DVC wouldn't do that.)

Answer (score 4):

The file you want to add (or the folder that contains it) is probably already in the *.gitgnore file*. If this is the case, you have to remove it first before doing a `dvc add`.

Answer (score 0):

Git might be tracking these files
To stop tracking from Git:

```
git rm -r --cached Training_Batch_Files
git commit -m "stop tracking Training_Batch_Files"
```

Your firewall may be blocking the same, hence disable it from blocking then run below command.

```
dvc add -R  Training_Batch_Files
```